# C++: std::map sorting

Tags: c++, dictionary, std

I am a newbie to C++, and this question may seem obvious to a lot of people.

If I write something like

```
std::map<int, double> m;
```

- Is m guaranteed to be sorted according to int order?
- Is it necessary to define a comparitor class to enforce the sorting?

For example,

```
class own_int_less : public binary_function<int, int, bool>
{
public:
    bool operator()( const double &left, const double &right  ) const
    {
        return (abs(left - right) > epsilon) && (left < right);
    };
    double epsilon;
};
```

- When is the sorting actually occurred? I mean does the sorting function get called every time I insert something into the map? Or does it get called before I iteration through the map?

Thanks.

Comment: You defined a `binary_function<int, int, bool>`, but your `operator()` is taking two `const double &` as parameters...

Comment: Be careful to initialize your member variables. (`epsilon`is never initialized in your example).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is m guaranteed to be sorted according to int order?

Yes.  The default comparator is `std::less<Key>`, which in your case is `std::less<int>`, which just uses `<` as expected.

> Is it necessary to define a comparitor class to enforce the sorting?

No, because the previous answer was "yes"!

> When is the sorting actually occurred?

A typical `map` implementation uses the comparator to insert a new element into the correct location.  The comparator is also used when doing a lookup.